# Turbo Power Asyncpro error on compiling

Tags: c++, serial-port, c++builder, c++builder-xe, turbopower

I have a C++ Builder XE project. I use additional packages from [**Turbo Power Async Professional**](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpapro/&ei=k_C2UYSPDYKErAeByoCADw&usg=AFQjCNFc9CRMvfNV8HGnxNhDxWsnFbfyfw&sig2=26AqYpsCQQD353Pv-iwDlw&bvm=bv.47534661,d.bmk) called TApdComport to enabling the communication with Serial Port.

However, I always got error message if I try to compile my project. Here is the message:

> [ILINK32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'ADPORT.OBJ'

I don't understand whats going wrong here. I've been install the packages correctly based on [this tutorial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41301&ei=XvK2Ub3aKI2qrAf8j4HAAw&usg=AFQjCNHdn9UzHp-9qpeXgYrO-Qa_63FSaQ&sig2=_wHEwWLG0lzXh0s8gx4HJw&bvm=bv.47534661,d.bmk&cad=rja) but that error always appeared.

It includes "ILINK32" which means the error is on linking process so I check my Include path and Library path in Tools>Option menu but nothing wrong on the path section.

Anyone can tell me how to solve a problem like this?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that the linker cannot find a file that satisfies an explicit dependency. Sometimes, one of the source files/headers is explicitly asking for this file via a #pragma link, but most of the time one of the .obj/.lib files you are linking against has an explicit dependency.

This is usually satisfied by adding a path to the linker's search paths.

Since you say there is nothing wrong with your linker paths, does that mean you've got an entry for the Turbo Power Libraries?

It is worth noting that the linker is sometimes satisfied with an appropriate .lib file, even though it asks for a specific .obj file, that may be available in a differently named .lib file.

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks for the answer. I've been including `tpapro_5.00\run` and `tpapro_5.00\packages\D2010` as the Include and Library path on my compiler's Tools Options but I still got that error message. In that directory, I can found the ADPORT file but in .pas extension, not in .obj extension. I've been Googling about that and knows that the .pas file is actually have a relationship with the .obj file but I don't understand about it details. Can you describe to me about that? Or you have any idea? Thank a lot in advance.